# why $3 - \sin{x}$ is always positive?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, logarithms

Hello I am currently learning integration and after integrating the function $\int \frac{\cos{x}}{3-\sin{x}}$ I end up with $-\ln{|3-\sin{x}|} + c$. However in the textbook it is stated that, since $3-\sin{x}$ can only take positive values, the answer is $-\ln{(3-\sin{x})} + c$.

I know it is very basic question but I want to make sure I understand this correctly.

> Does the $3-\sin{x}$ take only positive values because $\sin{x}$ can
>   output values between $-1$ and $1$, therefore the minimum $y$-value
>   can be $2$?

Please note that I do understand why integrating $\frac{1}{x} = \ln{x} + c$ for $x>0$

Comment: $\sin(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$, thus $3-\sin(x)\geq2>0$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @emiliocba The OP seems to understand that, as indicated in the highlighted text.

Comment: Your answer $-\ln |3-\sin x| + c$ is also correct, the absolute value is merely unnecessary, not wrong.

Comment: Yes I know that if the expression can take only positive values the absolute notation is unnecessary, but I still want to make sure that I do understand why the $3-\sin{x}$ is always positive in case that would be a preferred answer notation on the exams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

In mathematical words,
$$-1 \le \sin x \le 1$$
$$1 \ge -\sin x \ge -1$$
$$-1 \le -\sin x \le 1$$
$$3-1 \le 3-\sin x \le 3+1$$
$$2 \le 3-\sin x \le 4$$

So you get that $3-\sin x$ is always positive.